# How to augment an object with custom method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, factory

I'm wondering if there is some best-practice for how to give behavior to object received from the outside (a db, the network, etc) in javascript (nodejs).

For instance, assume I have some `getById(<Id>)` function which fetch the right object from a db, how would you add a `save`method on the object returned by this function?

Here is what I would like to have:

```
var getById = function (id) {
   var obj = callSomeExternalCode(id);
   return obj;
};
var myObj = getById('1234');
myObj.aProperty = 'a_new_value';
myObj.save();
```

I would prefer to avoid pseudo-classical solution (anyway, I may adapt it to my style if you can provide me with a good one)

Edit: I forgot to mention, it would be very nice to have these methods defined in a separate 'parent' object (even if, I suppose, proto-inheritance is not the answer)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it would be very nice to have these methods defined in a separate 'parent' object

Then just do so:

```
var parent = {
    save: function() {…}
};
function getById(id) {
    // There's a shortcut function called "extend" for this in many libs:
    // return extend(callSomeExternalCode(id), parent);
    // which does
    var obj = callSomeExternalCode(id);
    for (var p in parent)
        obj[p] = parent[p]; // copy
    return obj;
}
```

> I suppose, proto-inheritance is not the answer

It could be, especially if there are more properties on `parent` than on the new `obj`. Then you could do (even without any pseudo-classical code):

```
function getById(id) {
    // return extend(Object.create(parent), callSomeExternalCode(id));
    // long:
    var obj = callSomeExternalCode(id),
        res = Object.create(parent);
    for (var p in obj)
        res[p] = obj[p]; // copy
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I know that this may seems to be 'dirty' but as stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777641/storing-and-retrieving-javascript-objects-in-from-mongodb), it's possible to swap the 'prototype' object in v8....does it look like too much dirty to you?

Comment: Yes, I think the [non-standard `__proto__` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) is quite dirty - it won't work in IE as well. Of course a `Object.setPrototypeOf` might be handy sometimes, but I fear there is no standardized way...

Comment: oh, that won't be a problem, it's a node-only project :)
Anyway, I agree...as long as it's not fully standardized I feel uncomfortable with it :D

Answer (score 1):

why not pass the myObj to another factory / decorate object in front?

i.e.

```
myAugmentedObj = User.augment(myObj);
myAugmentedObj.save();
```

edit:

More concretely:

```
var UserModule = {
  save: function ( ... ) { ... },
  anotherFunction: function ( ... ) { ... }
};

var User = {
  augment: function (user) {
    return $.extend(user, UserModule);
  }
};
```

By the way,

I would actually make User a class, and have UserModule as part of it rather than a separate object, then create new objects as instances of User. But you explicitly mentioned avoiding classical inheritance.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was thinking about. The problem is how to implement the User.Augment function itself (I mean, copy from a template? some other technique?)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var getById = function (id) {
    var obj = callSomeExternalCode(id);

    obj.save = function() {
        // do something
    }

    return obj;
};
```

Comment: I edited the question to explain why I prefer to avoid this solution :) (anyway, isn't this duplicating the save function for each object?)

Comment: Yes, it is creating several `save` functions